# How to create record in seeds.rb that references another created record

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Imagine I want to seed data for a `BookSupplier` and `Book` tables.

```
BookSupplier.create(company: "Pablo Lledó - ProjectManagement", city: "Canadá", country: "Estados Unidos", address: "Victoria, BC, Canadá", telephone: "1", contact: "Limberg Morales", email: "", website: "")
Book.create(title: "Ajax", author: "Zakas, Nicholas C.- McPeak, Jeremy - Fawcett, Joe", edition: "", isbn: "84-415-2077-1", pages: "448", publish_date: "Septiembre 2006", cover: "libro_84-415-2077-1_1195672469.jpg")
```

How can I correctly associate that Book, to that BookSupplier? What's the proper way to handle this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With an intermediate variable to hold the supplier.

If they already have a relationship in your models, then:

```
pablo_lledo = BookSupplier.create(company: "Pablo Lledó - ProjectManagement")
Book.create(supplier: pablo_lledo)
```

Otherwise:

```
pablo_lledo = BookSupplier.create(company: "Pablo Lledó - ProjectManagement")
Book.create(supplier_id: pablo_lledo.id)
```